# Isolating a user

Tags: linux

In my Linux system I have two users, say A and B. I need to isolate B in such a way that B cannot be given access to A's home directory,even by A itself. How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Yes! B should be denied access from A's home directory even if A intents to do so by changing permissions.

Comment: Do users need root access? For example to install a package?

Answer (score 6):

Put the A's home directory into a directory for which B has no x (execution) bit set.

Example: Let `/home/prison/A` be the home directory of A. Set the permissions of `prison` to
`r-xr-x---` and the owner:group to `root:prisoners`. Set the permissions on `/home/prison/A` normally, i.e. `A` is the owner.

Naturally, A can still hard-link his files into other directories and make them accessible this way. There is really no way to protect data from users with read access and the will to duplicate them.

Answer (score 3):

[Thiton's answer](https://serverfault.com/q/333746/2101) is a good way solving this.

Another (heavier and more complex) fix is by creating an appropriate policy if you're using SELinux or AppArmour. You can enforce this at the system level and A won't be able to bypass it on the filesystem level (with AppArmour) or even by copying files (with SELinux).

Implementation of such a policy is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: SELinux, SMACK, or any other MAC framework is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for chroot, and someone has a project called [jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/howtos_chroot_shell.html) that appears to do just that.  Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

If nobody else needs access to files in the users home directory, you could make home directories executable/readable/writable *only* by that user.

```
sudo chmod 700 /home/username
```

Other users will not be able to see inside this directory, cd to it, etc.

Comment: … until A changes the permissions on the directory.